# C++ allocating class in stack, not in heap

Tags: c++

My question is, does the declaration below allocate on the stack, or on the heap?

```
List * aList = new List();
```

The objective is to have a pointer that points to an object in the stack.

Comment: *“The objective is to have a pointer in the stack.”* – I don't understand what that means.

Comment: The pointer is most likely on the stack, but there isn't enough context to know for sure.

Comment: The pointer is on the stack, the memory it points to is not ....

Comment: I clarified your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allocates from the heap. 
To get a pointer that points to stack memory, do

```
{
  List aList;
  List* pointer = &aList;
  // use aList or pointer here
  pointer->push(foo);
} // aList is destroyed here
```

Warning, don't save the pointer for later use, as aList is destroyed when the curly braces end the current block.

For example *DO NOT DO THIS*

```
List* pointer;
{
  List aList;
  pointer = &aList;;
} // aList is destroyed here

pointer->push(foo);  // oh uh, if you are lucky you get a crash; if not your
                     // data is corrupted
```

Comment: Saying `List aList;` makes the list on the stack but the nodes are still dynamically allocated from heap when added aren't they?  You need would need to feed it an allocator that uses a pool of stack memory wouldn't you?  Something like http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c18503/C-Programming-Stack-Allocators-for-STL-Containers.htm

Comment: `List` is not a standard C++ class, so I was just assuming it was the equivalent of `foo`.  If the OP meant something like `std::list`, then yes, of course, the actually elements inside the container are still on the heap.  If the OP wanted something like a 1-D container on the heap, the only way of doing that is using `std::array` (or a plain old `c` array), whose elements are in the same storage as the container.

Comment: My mistake!  I read List and thought std::list which it clearly isn't. Sorry.